# how to check if the value of a text input is empty right after the keypress event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, keypress

Here's the problem, in abstract terms: i have three input fields (A, B, C). two of them need to be text inputs (A and B), the third is of irrelevant type. I need to enable the third if A is not empty and B is not empty. I need to disable C if A is empty or B is empty.

The code

```
// empty is the empty function from the phpjs project
// framework used: jQuery
// A, B and C are classes here

$(".A, .B").keypress(function(){
   if( !empty($(".A").val()) && !empty($(".B").val()) )
       $(".C").attr("disabled","");
   else
       $(".C").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

I want to be able to check this on keypress, but when requesting the value of the input that is edited when the keypress event occurs i get the value that was calculated before the keypress event.

Has anybody stumbled upon this before and solved it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried using the keyUp event?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Attach your handler to the `keyrelease` event. The value should have been updated by then.

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of handlers for `keyup` and `change`. the `keyup` handler will update as the user types (excepting edge cases like holding a key down, which doesn't seem like a concern here) and the `change` handler will catch things like the user cutting the text with mouse actions before they can switch to field C. as an added measure you could add verification on field C's `focus` event, to make sure A and B really have something.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.A, .B').keydown(function(event) { 
    if(!empty($('.A').val()) && !empty($('.B').val()))
        $(".C").attr("disabled","");
    else
        $(".C").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

At the `keypress` event, the value of the `INPUT` is not yet set. Hence you can't easily know if it is empty.

While the `keyup` fires, the value of the `INPUT` is set.

But things get worse. The user can empty the field with the mouse or the Edit menu of the browser. In that case `keyup` is not fired.

In our web app we auto-save the values.
 Like in Mac OS, if you know, there is almost no save buttons.

To allow a reaction here is more or less what we do:

1. `onfocus`: a `setInterval` starts polling every 120ms or so, and checks the input for any change
2. if there is a change do the relevant action
3. `onblur`: a `clearInterval` stop the polling